# How'd you get previous 2 and next 2 elements from current index of any given array?

Tags: ruby

Given an array

`arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

I want a method that takes an **index** and an array

```rb
def previous_and_next_elems(idx, arr)
  ...
end
```

Say that `idx = 1`

```
$> previous_and_next_elems(1, arr)
$> [['a'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Note that since only single item was present before `idx=1` therefore only element `a` was there. If there was none then empty array would have returned.

Comment: Your title says "previous and next n elements in an array of any length" but your questions are all strictly based around an array with a length of 4 and with a range of 1 to 2 elements based on the index's relation to the length of the array. In short: your question is unclear and your examples don't help. Please take a moment to think through your actual question and provide multiple examples.

Comment: I put these questions based on an example. There could be an array of different length. What I only need is to get previous 2 and next 2 elements, by `n` I meant 2 but of course it could be any previous/next number if I have the logic.

I think I explained my question very well with the exact idea of what I really need.

Comment: I just updated my question and mentioned that it's not strictly for an array of 4 length. Hope you get my question.

Comment: `"d"` is the value of `arr` at index `3`. You should not call `"d"` an index. Even if you mean the index of `"d"`, suppose the array were `["a", "d", "c", "d"]`.

Comment: If my understand is correct, you could word the question as follows, "given an array `arr` and an index `i`, `0<=i<=arr.size-1`, return an array `[a,b]`, where `a` and `b` are (possibly empty) arrays, `a` contains (in order) `arr[i-2]` if `i-2 >= 0` and `arr[i-1]` if `i-1 >=0`, and `b` contains `arr[i+1]` if `i+1 <= arr.size-1`."

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is poorly worded. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. We need to see your attempt to solve this. Currently there's no evidence you wrote code. Did you research this? If not, why? If so, why didn't it help? Did you write code to solve it? If not, why? If so, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you're having? Without that information it looks like you're asking us to write a solution for you which is off-topic.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

```
def for_and_aft(arr, idx)
  index_range = 0..arr.size-1
  [arr.values_at(*[idx-2, idx-1].grep(index_range)),
   arr.values_at(*[idx+1].grep(index_range))]
end
```

```
for_and_aft(arr,0)
  #=> [[], ["b"]] 
for_and_aft(arr,1)
  #=> [["a"], ["c"]] 
for_and_aft(arr,2)
  #=> [["a", "b"], ["d"]] 
for_and_aft(arr,3)
  #=> [["b", "c"], ["e"]] 
for_and_aft(arr,4)
  #=> [["c", "d"], []]
```

See [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) and [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

Consider `idx = 1`. The following calculations are performed.

```
index_range = 0..arr.size-1
  #=> 0..4
```

```
a = [idx-2, idx-1]
  #=> [-1, 0] 
b = a.grep(index_range)
  #=> [0] 
c = arr.values_at(*b)
  #=> ["a"]
```

```
d = [idx+1]
  #=> [2] 
e = d.grep(index_range)
  #=> [2] 
f = arr.values_at(*e)
  #=> ["c"]
```

```
[c,f]
  #=> [["a"], ["c"]]
```

In computing `b`, `grep` uses [Range#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) to evaluate

```
(0..4) === -1
  #=> false 
(0..4) ===  0
  #=> true
```

and therefore returns `[0]`.

Comment: Why `.to_a` with `&` when you can `.to_set`? Or even better, `index_range = 0...arr.size` and then `[idx-2, idx-1].grep(index_range)`, super fast, no down sides.

Comment: @Amadan, thank you. Much better. I had tied a string around one finger as a reminder to "think grep", but I still forget. I still enjoy seeing that green helmet.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem in understanding my question when @CarySwoveland answered it perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

Just found a solution. A guy just helped me from slack.

```rb
def previous_and_next_two_from(element = 3, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  i = arr.index(element)
  next_two = i ? arr[(i + 1)..(i + 2)] : []
  i = arr.reverse.index(element)
  previous_two = i ? arr.reverse[(i + 1)..(i + 2)].reverse : []
  {
    previous_two: previous_two,
    next_two: next_two
  }
end

$> previous_and_next_two_from(0) => {:previous_two=>[],     :next_two=>[]     }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(1) => {:previous_two=>[],     :next_two=>[2, 3] }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(2) => {:previous_two=>[1],    :next_two=>[3, 4] }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(3) => {:previous_two=>[1, 2], :next_two=>[4, 5] }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(4) => {:previous_two=>[2, 3], :next_two=>[5]    }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(5) => {:previous_two=>[3, 4], :next_two=>[]     }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(6) => {:previous_two=>[],     :next_two=>[]     }
$> previous_and_next_two_from(7) => {:previous_two=>[],     :next_two=>[]     }
```

Exactly what I need. Cheers!

Comment: This won't work if you have repeated elements in the array. Not to mention it does a lot of unneeded things.

Comment: Well It doesn't matter in my case. Btw can you explain what are unneeded things here?

Comment: All the reversing. Also, your question talks about "index", but the answer has `element` instead — and if you have an index, `.index` is also unneeded (and dangerous).